# Very Basic Python 3.6 Plotting Issue

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, plot

So I have a rather easy question r.e. some plotting issues.  I have don't have the greatest level of Python knowledge, its been a few months since looking at it, there isn't anything that I can see that would aid me.

I have the following data frame:

```
        Date       Open       High        Low      Close   Adj Close   Volume
0 11/01/2018  86.360001  87.370003  85.930000  86.930000   86.930000 143660001
1 10/01/2018  87.000000  87.190002  85.980003  86.080002   86.080002 108223002
```

This isn't all of the data; there's 3000+ rows of it.

QUESTION: I'm trying to plot Adj Close vs. Date.  However, due to the index column, which I don't actually want, I end up with a plot of Adj Close vs. the index column.  No use obviously.

I've used:

```
bp['Adj Close'].plot(label='BP',figsize=(16,8),title='Adjusted Closing Price')
```

So really it's a case of, where do I put the ['Date'] part into the code, so the Index column isn't used?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need first convert column by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
bp['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(bp['Date'])
```

and then use `x` and `y` parameters in [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
bp.plot(x='Date', y='Adj Close', label='BP',figsize=(16,8),title='Adjusted Closing Price')
```

Or [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column `Date` and then use [`Series.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html):

```
bp.set_index('Date')['Adj Close'].plot(label='BP',figsize=(16,8),title='Adjusted Closing Price')
```